# Second Redirect if 1st Redirect fails

Tags: php, jsp, redirect

I have written this code to redirect visitors to the server hosted in my laptop(dynamic ip)

I use a second php script to update  the ip in the database

```
    <?php
    //redirect.php
    $con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_admin,$db_password);
    if (!$con){
        echo "Couldn connect to server !!";
    }
    $sql ="select ip from $db_name.redirect WHERE id=0";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $ip = "error.php";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ip=$row[0];
    }
    //Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
    $forward = "Location: http://$ip";
    header( $forward ) ;
    //Header(  "Location: errorMsg.php"); 
    ?>
```

But my laptop server is on only very rarely,
I was wondering if it is possible to redirect to *errorMsg.php* if the 1st redirect fails??

also is the same achievable with jsp??

Comment: In a word, no. Once you've sent the redirect, your connection with the client is (probably) dropped and you certainly have no control over its future behaviour. This is a limitation of the HTTP protocol itself, irrelevant of the server-side language. You would need a reverse proxy to do something like this. Or, I suppose, it could be done by serving an HTML document with a bit of Javascript with an instant redirect to URL 1 and a timer to redirect to URL 2 if the page is still loaded in the browser after n seconds - but that wouldn't be in any way reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could ping the IP, and if it does not respond, then use the errorMsg.php. Try this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_hostname;

try
{
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn,$db_admin,$db_password);
} catch(PDOEXception $e) {
        echo 'Couldn connect to server !!';
}

$sql = 'SELECT ip FROM redirect';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$ip = $sth->fetchColumn();
$location = 'errorMsg.php';
if($ip && $fp=fsockopen($ip,80,$en,$es,1)) {
        fclose($fp);
        $location = 'http://'.$ip;
}

header('Location: '.$location);
```

This assumes you have some way to update the database with the IP you want.

PS - I recommend PDO, if it was not obvious.

Comment: Thanks,the ping worked perfectly.
But what I don't get is why you suggested PDO. Can you elaborate?